# Compare Listview Subitems

Tags: vb.net, string, list, listview, compare

I am not so sure how i should code this properly:
I loop through all Listview Subitems.

```
If ListViewMain.Items.Count > 0 Then
        For Each Item As ListViewItem In ListViewMain.Items
            MsgBox(Item.SubItems(5).Text)
        Next
    End If
```

And only if the strings in the subitem of all items in the listview are the same show a "OK"-message, if only one is not the same like the others then show a "Not-Ok"-Message.
How can i do this the fastest, most efficiently way?
I thought about a List Of String and compare them somehow, other ideas?

Comment: Probably one of the most efficient ways is to not read your data back from the list.  The data should be held in an object (backing data) and manipulated as necessary, then just thrown to the listview when it needs displaying/has changed.

Comment: well, no. The data need to income always. I just need to perform this check time by time.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind I got it:)

```
   If Userlist.Any(Function(d) d <> Userlist(0)) Then
        'Different Items
    Else
        'Same items
    End If
```